# Text element in RaphaelJS not dragging on touch device

Tags: javascript, raphael

If I create a text element and add a drag handler it does not move on a touch device. I can see that the move event gets triggered, but the element does not drag. If I create a path element and attach the same drag handlers that path element moves just fine on a touch device. All elements move fine on both Chrome and Firefox on my laptop.

Is there anything special that I have to do to get text elements to drag on a touch device?

Here's a snippet of what I'm doing. I did remove some pieces of code that were unrelated, so it may look a little strange.

```
var word = paper.text(xVal, yVal, "text"]);
word.drag(window.move, window.start, window.up)

window.start = function() {
  this.lastDx = 0;
  this.lastDy = 0;
};

window.move = function(dx, dy) {
  this.transform("...T" + (dx - this.lastDx) + "," + (dy - this.lastDy));
  this.lastDx = dx;
  this.lastDy = dy;
  return this;

};

window.up = function() {
  this.lastDx = 0;
  this.lastDy = 0;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error I was able to get around this by creating a rectangle that "wraps" the text. I put a fill on the rectangle but with an opacity of 0 and then grouped the rectangle and the text together and made the set the draggable piece.

Comment: When you say 'grouped the rectangle and text together', is that using the `paper.set()` functionality in Raphael? If so, did you add the `.drag` to that set or to the rectangle?

Comment: Yeah, I used the set functionality. I did attach the drag to the set and wrote a function to move all of the elements contained within the set, effectively adding "dragability" to the set.

Answer (score 0):

There is a fix in Raphael 2.1.1 for this issue. Prior versions reported `NaN` for `dx`/`dy` on touch devices so if you were using those for dragging then it won't work.

See https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/issues/328